# MongoDB prototypal inheritance between persisted objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I curious if MongoDB has the option to save a object with another object (in the same schema) as its 'prototype'. For example:

Say we have an object in the db like so

```
{
  name : 'foo',
  lastName : 'bar',
  email : 'foo_bar@baz.com'
}
```

What i would like to do is get this object and update the email (for example)

so the new object would become this:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  lastName : 'bar',
  email : 'some_other_email@baz.com'
}
```

As you can see there's a duplicated data here (namely the name and lastName properties).

What i would like to do is save only the diffs so then the object would be on the email prop and a reft the original object like so

```
{
  email : 'some_other_email@baz.com',
  __proto__ : originalObjectId //or whatever
}
```

I know I can just update the object directly or save a new copy of the object but i would like to have immutability and not save the whole object every time, i would like to only save the diff from the original.

Is such a thing possible out of the box (by this i mean does mongo support and optimize such a this)? (or via some lib like mongoose or something)

Or would i have to implement it myself?

Cheers,
Boogie

Comment: can you name a database that has inheritance? We are now talking about duplicating data to achieve optimum speed. You try to minimize data size store on disk. Can you imagine how many hops to get through if you want to get a full object.

Comment: @wayne An object-relational database like PostgreSQL actually does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator which is an update operator aimed at only modifying the specified fields so you don't have to pass the whole object over the network just to keep it:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": idOfObjectOrOtherQuery },
    { "$set": { "email": "some_other_email@baz.com" }
)
```

So this is how updates generally work. Rather than replace the whole document you use an [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) instead, to just modify the parts you need.

MongoDB offers a **low level** interface to update operations, pretty much as shown. Part of what you seem to be talking about is a software layer on top of this to make those "diff" decisions for you. These are know as Object Document Mappers or ODM solutions, a counterpart to Object Relational Mappers or ORM's.

This is not the job of MongoDB as it is meant to be *lean* and flexible. The *job* of handling any further interaction is considered to be delegated to software libraries rather than the server. So you will find that some libraries such as "mongoose" for example, do exactly what has been shown. Where if you modify an object then the "delta" is detected and only the changes are sent to the server.

So you can either "re-invent the wheel", which you are perfectly welcome to do, or you can look at the solutions already "built on top of" the technology that use the base operations as provided.

Comment: This is not exactly what i meant. I would like to have an immutable database. Basically there would no updates only inserts and i would like the options to not insert a whole new record, but insert only the diffs between the old object and the new object.

Comment: @boogie Yes, well somewhat vague in how you asked this. More information to point you to what is happening here and what already exists. Not the Job of MongoDB to do this. And it should not be. Adds complexity.

Answer (score 0):

No MongoDB doesn't support this, you would have to implement this yourself.

Inheritance is a feature of an object system, but MongoDB works with documents which just coincidentally use an object notation (BSON).